# django-facebook connect users, but doesn't fill admin tables with any data

Tags: django, django-admin, django-facebook

I'm successfully using django-facebook to login facebook users 
( e.g, after login,  the template tag `{{ user }}` shows the facebook username). however, it doesn't make it to admin interface - and under `facebook users` there is no data at all.

also, the SQL table `django_facebook_facebookcustomuser` is showing the user data.

my guess was that i needed to register the `FacebookCustomUser` model in admin.py, so i did this -

```
class FacebookCustomUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(models.FacebookCustomUser, FacebookCustomUserAdmin)

# and commented out the user admin inteface -
#admin.site.register(models.FacebookUser, FacebookUserAdmin)
```

it solved the problem, but in a very hackish way...
I now have a 'users' table, showing the different users, but the 'open graph share' and 'like' sections are still not populated with any data from the db.

when i actually try to pass something inside the CustomUser class, as in the original code -

```
 class FacebookCustomUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('user_id', 'name', 'facebook_id',)
    search_fields = ('name',)
```

i get the following http500 error -

```
FacebookCustomUserAdmin.list_display[0], 'user_id' is not a callable or an attribute of 'FacebookCustomUserAdmin' or found in the model 'FacebookCustomUser'.
```

does anyone have an idea on how i can correctly register the facebook users ( as well as the other django-facebook models ) to the admin site?

**thanks a lot!**

Comment: I am having the same issue! Any insights?!

Answer (score 0):

Two pointers:

1. Extend `UserAdmin` instead of `ModelAdmin`.
2. Use `id` instead of `user_id`.

*Try this:*

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django_facebook import models
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

class AccountAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'facebook_id')

admin.site.register(models.FacebookCustomUser, AccountAdmin)
```

In `settings.py` you will need to add the following options to make sure likes and friends are saved:

```
FACEBOOK_STORE_LIKES = True
FACEBOOK_STORE_FRIENDS = True
```